# Can I use Format instead of using substring?

Tags: c#, string, substring

Using a memory profile on my C# desktop app I have found that strings are not being released from memory causing a slow and gradual buildup.

I have this code:

```
var ToYYYMMDDHHMMSS = "YYYMMDDHHMMSS";
var toYR = ToYYYMMDDHHMMSS.Substring(0, 4);
var toMN = ToYYYMMDDHHMMSS.Substring(4, 2);
var toDY =ToYYYMMDDHHMMSS.Substring(6, 2);
var toHR = ToYYYMMDDHHMMSS.Substring(8, 2);
var toMI = ToYYYMMDDHHMMSS.Substring(10, 2);
var motionPath = string.Format("{0}\\Catalogues\\{1}\\{2}\\{3}\\{4}\\{5}\\{6}", Shared.MOTION_DIRECTORY, camIndex, toYR, toMN, toDY, toHR, toMI);
```

Is there an alternative to using the substring? Can I use String.Format someway to get my desired result?

NB
I am so sorry for my poor phrasing of my question..

var ToYYYMMDDHHMMSS = "YYYMMDDHHMMSS";

I should have added that "YYYMMDDHHMMSS" is a timestamp that always changes
{apologies)

Comment: if you just need them once, define them as const not variables

Comment: Well firstly, I'd suggest that this isn't the cause of a memory leak unless you're doing something to *make* it a memory leak. Now, is your *real* value an actual `DateTime` value, formatted as `yyyyMMddHHMMss`? If so, I'd suggest parsing it as a `DateTime` - that'll make everything *much* simpler.

Comment: `ToYYYMMDDHHMMSS` is constant, thus all your `to*` can be precalculated, and lots of the path parameters are fixed.

Comment: @dotctor Hi, the values are constantly changing

Comment: and there might be something wrong with both month and minute are considered as "MM"

Comment: @dotctor HI again. Just a bad naming convention.  But point taken - thanks

Comment: you mean `toYR`, `toMN` and ... are changing? how?

Comment: @doctor The app is reading images froma cctv camera.  the timestamp is for each image acquired. In the end those numbers wil change too

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, then you can simply use [string.Format for Date and Time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).
Something like, 
`string.Format("{0:yyyy}\\{1:MM}...", DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now));`

Comment: @SimonSvensson hi, thanks for the comment,  I guess that would help by changing only as when. thanks

Comment: Strings are subject to garbage collection just as any other object. The exception is strings that were defined in your program code, they are interned, and any strings you intern yourself, these are remembered until the program closes, but all other strings are collected when/if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that your real code has a value of something like `20150225071945` - so not actually the literal `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS`. If that's the case, I would parse the value as a `DateTime` rather than extracting substrings:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(text, "yyyyMMddHHmmss",
                                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var motionPath = string.Format(@"{0}\Catalogues\{1:yyyy\\MM\\dd\\HH\\mm\\ss}",
                               Shared.MOTION_DIRECTORY, dateTime);
```

Note that the format string itself is a verbatim string literal, so you don't need to escape backslashes - but I've got `\\` in the format string for the `DateTime` because the `DateTime` formatting code will treat `\` as an escape.

An alternative would be to format each part of the date separately:

```
var motionPath = string.Format(@"{0}\Catalogues\{1:yyyy}\{1:MM}\{1:dd}\{1:HH}\{1:mm}\{1:ss}",
                               Shared.MOTION_DIRECTORY, dateTime);
```

Or use `Path.Combine`:

```
var motionPath = Path.Combine(Shared.MOTION_DIRECTORY,
                              "Catalogues",
                              dateTime.ToString("yyyy"),
                              dateTime.ToString("MM"),
                              dateTime.ToString("dd"),
                              dateTime.ToString("HH"),
                              dateTime.ToString("mm"),
                              dateTime.ToString("ss"));
```

Comment: Yes, I phrased my question poorly. Still too early for me :). Your answer is what I needed - thank you very much. I will edit my question now

Comment: I suggest using `Path.Combine` instead of `string.Format` since it is related to generating a path.

Comment: @dotctor: Yes, that will end up looking uglier, but more platform-neutral. Although using forward slashes would work too. Will add an example.